# How to export polygon coordinates to CSV (not WKT)?

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinates, export

I am trying to export polygon coordinates from a shapefile to a CSV file, but so far all my attempts have failed. I have found numerous questions and answers about this, but none have solved my problem.

I have downloaded the file

www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip

which is a shapefile containing a basic world map. I have imported the shapefile into QGIS by adding a vector layer, and then I try to export the polygons with coordinates for each country. The tips that I have found suggest either saving the layer by right-clicking it and then selecting Save as or opening the attribute table and copying it into Excel. If I try these I only get master information with one row for each country in the map.

Does anyone know how I can retrieve detail information for each country containing the polygons with coordinates?

Comment: So you want coordinates for all vertices ("corners") for all polygons exported? That could be quite a lot of rows. What you probably get now is the centroid. Can I ask what you need this for - maybe there's an easier way to accomplish what you want to do?

Comment: Would Well know Text(WKT) representation be enough for you?

Comment: I am not familiar with WKT, but from what I have found on the web it seems that it will be a bit difficult for me to use. I need the data in a csv file. 

The shape file I am using here is only for testing, I will not use it in my work. I am working with some special geograpghical zones related to fisheries. These zones are stored in a database. I would like to import the shape file data into the database for comparison purposes. I was hoping that I could find a way of exporting the coordinates for one chosen country in my test file to a csv file and then import it into the data base.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the plugin MMQGIS to export geometry to csv. I just try with your file, it works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Great! I think this may solve my problem! Here I am able to connect attributes and nodes. The real files that I will be working with will be much smaller than my very large test file. I think this is just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! Unfortunately my reputation is still too low to vote anything useful.

Comment: This worked for me and saved time. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Choose `Layer > Save As...` with format as CSV. Make sure 'Layer Option', 'GEOMETRY' is set to `AS_WKT` in the 'Save vector layer as...' window. The first column of the CSV file will now include polygon coordinates.

Comment: That worked! I got the coordinates! However, it will be a bit awkward using them as I need the data in a CSV file. I don't know if there is any easy way of converting from this format to csv. But this was very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple app to load a shapefile, and then export as X/Y's

http://www.qarah.com/shapeviewer/#download

Comment: That worked too! But here it seems I will have some problems connecting the coordinates to a country. If I export the attribute table with the country names I can find no obvious relation between the two data sets. I need both the master and detail information. But this is a neat little app that I will continue using. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A Greek way: A) Select the feature you want, copy it and paste onto a word processor. B) delete the first part `wkt_geom…` and the parenthesis at the end so there are only numbers. C) Replace: `,`(comma and one space) with `^p` (MS word) or `\n` (Libre office-Open office) D) replace one space  with comma. You get the list of coordinates in the X,Y format.