# Aegean Islands Spatial Dataset

Tags: data, spatial-database, greece

I need a .csv file about the coordinates of all the Islands in Aegean Sea. Do you have any idea how I can find them?

Comment: Try http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the "nomoi ΟΚΧΕ" which is available on the internet (link).This is a shapefile that contains all the regions of Greece.Then you can import it in a GIS software and select the islands that you are after.Finally you export it in a shp format and you are done.

http://opendatagortynia.gr/group/geography

1. Visit the above page
2. Find Nomoi OKXE
3. Press as Shapefile
4. Happy mapping

Comment: Glad my answer helped.You can press the checkmark to the most helpful answer as well.

Comment: "I installed ArcGIS and ArcMAP. Although I managed to open the file with ArcMAP, I couldn't export it. It only exports as PDF, JPEG etc. I'm not very familar with this program and don;t know what to do exactly. Can you help me please?

Comment: After you select the features you want go to the "Table Of Contents" table on the far left of your ArcMap window where your layers are located.There, right click on the name of the layer you have your islands in and choose "data" then "export data..." and then "ok".If you do that you will have created a new shapefile with your selected features. Are you attending Harokopeio?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see the feature in this content. I guess that's the problem. I only see the whole "nomoi ΟΚΧΕ" as a layer. By the way, I'm attending NPS currently.

Comment: I just figure out that layer consists of many polygons. So, I guess I need to select the polygons and export them. By the way, I need to include Turkey's coastline as well. So, I opened a Turkey map together. But I need to export those polygons

Comment: I created it as you said, sorry for the question bombardment. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could use free and open OpenStreetMap data. They are licensed under Open Database License (ODbL).

Geofabrik provides a website where you can download the [entire Greece-dataset as a shapefile](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/greece.html). After downloading, open the shapefile in a GIS of your choice (e.g. [qgis](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)) and select all entries which lie within the [OSM-relation of the Aegean Sea](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/4594226#map=7/37.653/27.334). After selecting all polygons [export them as a csv](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109553/how-to-export-polygon-coordinates-to-csv-not-wkt).