# Coordinates calculation using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am quite new to GIS software. I use QGIS. I have a question that might be trivial. I would like to derive the coordinates (Y and X) for an area. Just to make an example: I have two regions A and B. From the shapefile I know which are their coordinates. However, I would need the coordinates for the unique region A+B. Could you please give me some hints on how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "coordinates for an area"? An area does not have coordinates, a point does.

Comment: Yes you are right. I mean lon and lat for the points determining the region (A+B). It seems to me that field calculator should be used, but I am a bit lost with it.

Comment: What do you mean by region A+B? Depending on what you mean that, you could do something like a merge or intersection, then extract the coordinates of the vertices. Just make sure that the geoprocessing step that you use is consistent with what you mean by A+B.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I mean is the following.  Example: In the original shape file I have information about the coordinates to plot Spain an Portugal. I need to plot them as a single area. Therefore, I need the coordinates to plot spain+Portugal as they were only one country. So if I understood correctly, you suggest to merge them and to extract the coordinates of the vertices. This should work for my case.   I presume that I can merge them highlighting those two countries on the map. But then how can I extract the coordinates of the vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the precisions you provided in the comments, I understand that what you want is actually a *polygon merging* followed by some kind of vertices coordinates export. This is actually quite simple:

1. Merging: Select your layer then click on the pen icon to toggle edition mode. Select your two polygons, then go to Edit > Merge Selected Features. This will replace your two polygons with their geometric union (so if you want to keep your old polygons, make a copy of the layer first). This will work well if there are no gaps or overlap between your polygons.
2. Coordinates export: there are (at least) 2 options. You can right click on the layer, then "Save As..."; in the "Format" field, choose CSV. In "Layer options", "Geometry" field, choose "AS_WKT". Alternatively, you can install and use the MMQGIS plugin (see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/109563/64955) for reference).

Comment: Union still has the border in the middle. Dissolve using `Dissolve all` creates one polygon covering all elements.

Comment: @AndreJ: you're absolutely right: I confused union with the merge tool. I'll correct the answer.