# Contour lines (*.shp) into XYZ

Tags: qgis, elevation, xyz

I downloaded a TIFF image from USGS Earth Explorer from which I determined the contour lines and saved them in a shapefile (see tutorial http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_terrain.html).

I would like to convert these features to points (just as this ArcGIS tool http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-point.htm).

Each point should contain xyz information (simple CSV file or similar) which I can import as a surface elevation into FEFLOW (groundwater modelling)

I tried with MMQGIS which gives me the following output:

`"shapeid","x","y"
"1","-7.4266662066","37.1800028654"
"1","-7.42583287327","37.1800083477"
"1","-7.42582462244","37.1800000968"
"2","-7.42583287327","37.1799959509"
"3","-7.4266662066","37.1799959509"
"3","-7.42749953994","37.1797223191"
"3","-7.42833287327","37.1795834302"
"3","-7.4291662066","37.1797917635"
"4","-7.42999953994","37.1797223191"
"4","-7.43083287327","37.1799959509"
"4","-7.43083701921","37.1800000968"
"4","-7.4316662066","37.1805556524"
"4","-7.43208287327","37.1808334302"`

What I want however is:

`"x","y","z"
"Latitude","Longitude","Elevation"`

Comment: there is the option to export the .shp to .csv using the 'save-as' dialog, and there is the mmqgis plugin, which offers good control over .csv export. but I don't think you can actually export each vertex' z value, as the height is (I guess) only stored as a seperate column as contour level. could you refer to this column later in FEFLOW to get z values? you should also consider exporting the geometries as WKT (it is further explained in other question like this one; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109553/how-to-export-polygon-coordinates-to-csv-not-wkt)

Comment: ah I just saw that I linked a question that asks exactly for a solution without WKT...nonetheless, the right answer is there, too. you'll get both answers for one click, then. nice.

Comment: Hi @ThingumaBob! Thank you very much for your response! Unfortunately, this doesn't do it. I modified my question to clarify what I would like to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two steps:

1. Extract nodes. `Vector | Geometry Tools | Extract nodes` (or from Processing Toolbox `QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector geometry tools | Extract nodes`
2. `Save As...` the produced Nodes layer as csv file. By default, the `Geometry type` would be `Automatic` . Make sure the `Layer Options` is set to `GEOMETRY`= `AS_XY`. (So, basically, leave it as is).

NB the extracted nodes can create a big file. Please consider decimating it before saving it to csv.

Comment: This still exports the ID which is a little bit annoying but certainly something I can deal with!<br/>


`X,Y,ID,ELEV
-7.45249953993674,37.1912500968475,222308,0.000
-7.45208287327007,37.1916667635141,222308,0.000
-7.45249953993674,37.1920834301808,222308,0.000
-7.45277731771452,37.1916667635141,222308,0.000`
<br/>

Thank you both for your support!! :)

Comment: If you are using recent version such as QGIS2.18, you can select fields to export while saving it to csv.